# Jitterbit as an ETL tool

Tags: data-warehouse, etl, business-intelligence, jitterbit

anybody have used [Jitterbit](http://www.jitterbit.com) as an ETL tool? any reviews/tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Jitterbit and I have found it easy to use and they are a pretty responsive company to work with.

Since the question was posted they have added several webinars to their website that give you a good introduction to what you can do with the product:

[Jitterbit Integration Webinars](http://www.jitterbit.com/Product/integration-webinars.php)

Answer (score 0):

Jitterbit Developers added some small Tutorials:
[link text](http://www.jitterbit.com/Product/documents.php)

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty good and easy to use.

Very good in transformation. It has auto mapping tool, these is a way you can map source and destination pretty easily.

GUI is pretty strait forward and very user friendly.

It has lot many file operations. You can access FTP, Share, Local file, HTTP, LDAP etc etc

Web service is also very well written.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Jitterbit for integrating local PostgreSQL database with the salesforce